# Delete a pointer to be erased from a vector

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector, delete-operator, erase

Say I have a vector of pointers to "`Order`" objects. Now I want to remove an order from this vector. I wonder if the following is the right way to remove such a pointer?

```
std::vector<Order*> orders; 

// somehow I obtained a vector of Order*, and an iterator it that points to
// an order that I want to remove completely. 

// does the following work? 
Order *order = *it;
orders.erase(it);
delete order;
```

Comment: That'll work. But you might consider smart pointers or Boost ptr_vector.

Comment: Once erase is called will `order == NULL`?

Comment: Be sure the `order` object has been created with `new` and is not shared with other, causing a dangling pointer

Comment: @ahenderson no, it cannot affect `order` value (a pointer). Also `delete order` does not change `order` value. It continue pointing to the same area, even if after `delete` is is an invalid area.

Comment: @Alessandro: Actually, I think `delete order;` is permitted to set `order` to a null pointer. At least Bjarne Stroustrup says so in his C++ style/FAQ, that might be out of date and I can't be bothered to check ;-) In practice, I don't think any implementation bothers.

Comment: *C++ explicitly allows an implementation of delete to zero out an lvalue operand, and I had hoped that implementations would do that, but that idea doesn't seem to have become popular with implementers.* **Why doesn't delete zero out its operand?** http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#delete-zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was the pointer the result of `new`? Has anyone else deleted it first? If "yes" and "no", then your code will delete the object.

Comment: Are there any other copies of the pointer? If "yes", then you've just turned them into lethal deathtraps.

Comment: I second Mike Seymour's comment. Also do not forget to set 'order = NULL' or 'order = nullptr' (if you are using C++0x) after you have performed the deletion.

Comment: I agree with Mike too, I'm not advocating dynamic allocation, just explaining how `delete` works. I mostly disagree with setting pointers to `null` after deleting them. Code that deletes something almost always should in any case be designed so that the pointer goes out of scope pretty much immediately afterwards. In the very rare cases where that's not the case (such as perhaps in the `reset` function of a smart pointer), sure, setting it to null might indicate "nothing to see here". But as I say, that's rare, and should not be encouraged just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 3):

This will delete the order object. So yes this is the correct way.
Nevertheless you should think about the usage of smart pointers like `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. this is the right way. Containers do not delete their content when it's erased.